# Finding Mnemonics for expressions with lots of indices

Tags: string-manipulation, searching, cryptography, dictionary

One of the equations I work with in my research are the pentagon equations:

```
F[a,b,r,e,p,s]*F[p,c,d,e,q,r] == Sum[(F[b,c,d,s,x,r]*F[a,b,c,q,p,x]*F[a,x,d,e,q,s],{x,1,n}]
```

where `a,b,c,d,e,p,q,r,s,x` are indices of which the symbol is free to choose. Remembering such an equation would be much easier if these indices would be letters such that the strings `p,c,d,e,q,r`,`a,b,r,e,p,s`, etc would be words. For example if I chose the the letters `d,o,a,t,i,e,n,g,s` instead of `a,b,c,d,e,p,q,r,s` then the pentagon equations would become

```
F[d,o,g,i,e,s] F[e,a,t,i,n,g] = (a mess)
```

and thus the left hand side would be easy to remember (the RHS is still horrible though).

Saddly, there are no pairs of 6 letter words for which both the LHS and RHS are nice. I could of course allow for more freedom and demand that {a,b,r,e,p,s,p,c,d,e,q,r,b,c,d,s,x,r,a,b,c,q,p,x,a,x,d,e,q,s} (All indices written after each) other forms a list of words that may have different length.  This looks a lot like a cryptography problem, but my knowledge of cryptography is kind of non-existing.

So the question is: how would one use Mathematica to find characters a,b,c,d,e,p,q,r,s,x, such that the list of characters above would become a list of words?

Undoubtly there will be many solutions but a few would suffice (one is already amazing, but if more can be found that would be great).

---

The code I used to find 5 6-letter words that match the pattern of the pentagon indices is the following (Though I doubt that it will be of much use):

```
(* List of 6 letter words with distinct characters *)
wordList = 
  DictionaryLookup[
    a_ ~~ b_ ~~ r_ ~~ e_ ~~ p_ ~~ s_ /; 
    DuplicateFreeQ[ ToLowerCase @ {a, b, r, e, p, s} ] 
  ];

(* Create pairs of words that match the indices of LHS *)
wordPairs1[ wordList_, str_String ]:=Module[{
  chars = Characters[str],
  a,b,c,d,e,p,q,r,s},
  {a,b,r,e,p,s} = chars;
  {str,#} & /@
  Cases[
    wordList,
    S_String/;
    StringMatchQ[ S, p~~c_~~d_~~e~~q_~~r /; DuplicateFreeQ[ToLowerCase@{a,b,c,d,e,p,q,r,s}]]
  ]
]

(* Finds 5 words whose letters match the indices of the equation *)
wordQuintuples[ wordList_][ { str1_String, str2_String } ] := Module[{
firstMatches, a, b, c, d, e, p, q, r, s, properStrings, 
  lowerWords = ToLowerCase[wordList] },
  {a,b,r,e,p,s} = Characters[str1];
  {p,c,d,e,q,r} = Characters[str2];
  firstMatches = 
    Cases[ 
      wordList, 
      S_String /; 
      StringMatchQ[ 
        S, 
        b~~c~~d~~s~~x_~~r /; 
        DuplicateFreeQ[ ToLowerCase@{a,b,c,d,e,p,q,r,s,x} ] 
    ]
  ];
  properStrings[ str_String ] := With[{
    x = Characters[str][[5]],
    s1 = ToLowerCase[StringJoin[a,b,c,q,p,Characters[str][[5]]]], 
    s2 = ToLowerCase[StringJoin[a,Characters[str][[5]],d,e,q,s]]
    },
    If[ 
      MemberQ[ lowerWords, s1 ] && MemberQ[ lowerWords, s2 ],
      {str1,str2,str,s1,s2},
      {}
    ]
  ];
  DeleteCases[{}] @ (properStrings /@ firstMatches)
]
```

The result is that there exists no letters for the indices that give nice 6 letter words for all factors.

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to use sentences as mnemonics, with words starting with the letter of interest, Example (not an easy one. Ideally, the five sentences should tell a story): ```F[a,big,reader,enjoys,playing,sax]*F[playing,cop,does,entail,questioning,readers==F[big,cop,does,six,xerox,readers]*F[a,big,cop,questions,playing,xerox]*F[a,xerox,does,entail,questioning,Sax]```

Comment: Maybe it is better to use numbers instead of letters?

Answer (score 1):

> Spoiler Alert: There is no word that can have meaning in 5 different orders.

### Workflow

After ordering the characters, you will get this:

```
(* string you want *)
s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10


F[s1,s2,s8,s5,s6,s9], F[s6,s3,s4,s5,s7,s8]

F[s2,s3,s4,s9,s10,s8], F[s1,s2,s3,s7,s6,s10], F[s1,s10,s4,s5,s7,s9]
```

Print the numbers via `NumberLinePlot` to help you build the solution:

```
NumberLinePlot[{{1, 2, 8, 5, 6, 9}, {6, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8}, {2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 8}, {1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 10}, {1, 10, 4, 5, 7, 9}}]
```

[image]

- Since there are no 2 rows that cover all letters, I pick yellow, blue and green rows in order to find words (you can choose any combination as long as it covers all letters) like:

[image]

1- Create a list of 6 unique letter (using `DuplicateFreeQ`) words. I pick yellow row from above plot and find words base on that:

```
yellowWords = DictionaryLookup[
   x__ /; StringLength[x] == 6 && 
     DuplicateFreeQ@ToLowerCase@Characters[x]];

(*Output Length: 5049 *)
```

2- Define a function that finds blue words from given yellow word (base on the intersection of yellow and blue row from the plot):

```
findBlueWords[yellowWord_] := 
  Select[DictionaryLookup[
    StringExpression[_, _, #1, #2, #3, _] & @@ 
     StringPart[yellowWord, {3, 4, 6}], IgnoreCase -> True], 
   DuplicateFreeQ@ToLowerCase@Characters@# &];
```

3- Define another function to find green word from given yellow and blue words:

```
findGreenWords[yellowWord_, blueWord_] := 
  Select[DictionaryLookup[
    StringExpression[#1[[1]], #2[[1]], #2[[2]], #1[[2]], #1[[3]], _] \
& @@ {StringPart[blueWord, {2, 5, 6}], 
      StringPart[yellowWord, {1, 2}]}, IgnoreCase -> True], 
   DuplicateFreeQ@ToLowerCase@Characters@# &];
```

4- Map functions to yellow words with a little bit of tweaking:

```
result = Flatten[
  Tuples[{{#[[1, 1]]}, {#[[1, 2]]}, #[[2]]}] & /@ ({#, 
       findGreenWords @@ #} & /@ 
     Flatten[Tuples[{{#[[1]]}, #[[2]]}] & /@ 
       Map[{#, findBlueWords[#]} &, yellowWords], 1]), 1]
```

- in step 4 you will find letters that meet 3 of your 5 criteria, like:

```
 {..., {"inroad", "strode", "tinder"}, {"lichen", "techno", "Elinor"}, ...}
```

5- But if you filter it base on if they have meaning in other 2 criteria, you will get None:

```
filterNonSenseWordsOrRepeatedLetters[{yellowWord_, blueWord_, 
   greenWord_}] := 
 Module[{orangeWord, purpleWord, 
   yl = ToLowerCase@Characters@yellowWord, bl = Characters@blueWord, 
   gl = ToLowerCase@Characters@greenWord},
  
  purpleWord = 
   StringJoin[bl[[1]], yl[[2]], yl[[3]], yl[[5]], gl[[5]], gl[[6]]];
  orangeWord = 
   StringJoin[bl[[1]], gl[[1]], gl[[2]], yl[[4]], yl[[5]], gl[[6]]];
  Return[DictionaryWordQ@purpleWord && DictionaryWordQ@orangeWord && 
    DuplicateFreeQ@Characters@purpleWord && 
    DuplicateFreeQ@Characters@orangeWord];
  ]

Select[result, filterNonSenseWordsOrRepeatedLetters]

(*Out: {} *)
```

#### Plot Results

This function will plot three words, but you can change it to show those other nonsense words:

```
drawWords[w1_, w2_, w3_] := Module[{},
  Graphics@{
    MapIndexed[Text[#1, {{3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}[[#2[[1]]]], 2}] &, Characters@w1],
    MapIndexed[Text[#1, {{1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9}[[#2[[1]]]], 1}] &, Characters@w2],
    MapIndexed[Text[#1, {{2, 3, 4, 8, 9, 10}[[#2[[1]]]], 3}] &,Characters@w3]}]
```

Sample:

```
drawWords["amours", "arouse", "Ramsey"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `WordList` to get words for your pattern.

E.g. for your example:`F[a,b,r,e,p,s]*F[p,c,d,e,q,r]`. We must first get a list of words with 6 characzers:

```
words = Select[WordList["KnownWords", IncludeInflections -> True], 
   StringLength[#] == 6 &] // ToLowerCase;
```

Now we select words that correspond to the pattern: `F[a,b,r,e,p,s]`:

```
Select[t, 
 StringMatchQ[#, 
   StringExpression[a_, b_, r_, e_, p_, s_] /;  a != b != r != e != p != s] &]

(* {"abduce", "abduct", "abhors", "abides", "abient", "abject", \
"abjure", "ablest", "ablism", "abodes", "abohms"...} *)
```

Now assume we choose "abduc" and need a word for `F[p,c,d,e,q,r]`. Because of `F[a,b,r,e,p,s]` the symbols p,e,r already have values of "u","d","b" so the search pattern is:

```
Select[t, 
 StringMatchQ[#, StringExpression["u", c_, d_, "d", q_, "b"] /;  FreeQ[{"u", "d", "b"}, c | d | q]] &]
```

This does not find any word. Therefore we need to try another word, e.g. "abduct". I leave this search to you. Of course, one may also automate this, but I think it is not worth the time.